# How to get GLTFLoader to work in three js

Tags: javascript, model, loading, blender, gltf

i set up a new html file to use three.js and literally copy pasted the example code from the GLTFLoader documentation and nothing's working, can anyone help? I can run three js just fine when i load a cube but it seems not to be recognizing the GLTFLoader.js file.

If anyone knows why this is happening (or NOT happening) plz let me know. <3

```
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
<script src="js/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script>

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(light);

    var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    scene.add(light2);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer. setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var loader = new GLTFLoader();
    
    // Load a glTF resource
    loader.load(
        // resource URL
        'pentaprism.glb',
        // called when the resource is loaded
        function ( gltf ) {
    
            scene.add( gltf.scene );
    
            gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
            gltf.scene; // THREE.Group
            gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Group>
            gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
            gltf.asset; // Object
    
        },
        // called while loading is progressing
        function ( xhr ) {
    
            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
    
        },
        // called when loading has errors
        function ( error ) {
    
            console.log( 'An error happened' );
    
        }
    );


    function update() {
        
    }


    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        update();

        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    }
    animate();

</script>
```

Comment: If you look at the source code for that file you see something like `import { ..., sRGBEncoding
} from "../../../build/three.module.js";` and so copying that file breaks the reference it has to three.module.js.If you want to go brute force, instead of using `npm`/`yarn`/`esm`, you can copy the entire three.js code and that could get it working, but it makes more sense to use `esm`, in this case that would be `import * as THREE from 'three'` and `import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'`

Comment: I copied the three.module.js file into the js folder and changed the dependencies of the GLTFLoader imports and it still didnt work, and i tried changing my code to what you suggest and it still didnt work. Anything i'm doing wrong?

The browser debugger says  Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.

I added these two lines of code:
     var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

Comment: Does https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation help? If you're using files that include imports/exports, you have to import them. Using `<script src="GLTFLoader.js"></script>` will not work.

Comment: So i tried what that page said and i got this error: Access to script at 'file:///C:/three' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. I can't even import the basic three code now let alone the loader. Now what?

Comment: I also saw that it was taking the file path directly from the C: directory so i changed to where i installed 'three with npm in the node_modules folder, and i got the same error.

Comment: Read that installation guide very carefully, including the links within such as https://eloquentjavascript.net/20_node.html#h_J6hW/SmL/a
The three.js install guide has a couple of options; npm install, and static install. In the static version, makes sure to use type="module" on your script tag or else you will get the `Cannot use import statement outside a module.` error. In the case of CORS policy error, you might want to use something like `serve` which can be installed with `npm i -g serve` for example, which will run your project on localhost which should fix the CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been trying to learn how to use the GLTFLoader.js.

Not sure if it's quite what you are looking for, but perhaps this video will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4q2cqj_Tdc

Some things he does differently, if I remember correctly are:
Uses <script **type="module"** src="GLTFLoader.js">
and var loader = **new THREE.GLTFLoader();**
and he uses jsm files instead of js files.

Hope it helps! Good luck :--)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29817082)